# Unrecognized IP address showing when hostname -I entered into terminal

Tags: networking, ip-address, hostname, ip-camera

This has been the case since I tried installing some now uninstalled software on my Linux laptop to connect to an IP camera network (Hikvision cameras and DVR recording device via a docker image). How can I verify that this unrecognized IP address is no longer needed and how to remove it?

Comment: Use `ifconfig` or `ip address` to see which interface the IP is configured on, and add it to your question. Docker may have left a virtual interface you can remove or disable. For example, bridge interfaces usually get named dockerX, and can be removed with `ip link del docker0`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale This comment was the answer to my query. If you care to repost this comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ifconfig` or `ip address` to see which interface the IP is configured on.

Docker may have left a virtual interface you can remove or disable. For example, bridge interfaces usually get named dockerX, and can be removed with `ip link del docker0`